# Windows 8 C++ Qt Add New User

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am trying to create a user management tool using Qt and C++. I have duplicated a similar dialog window similar to the "New User" dialog in Computer Management on Windows 8.

Can anyone advice how can I go about coding it to save the data keyed into my user management tool in Qt into Windows?

Comment: Do you mean save the data into a text file in Windows? Just use QFile.

Comment: Are you managing Windows user accounts or other accounts? There are no APIs in Qt for admin tasks such as user management, that requires platform-specific code.

Comment: @sashoalm: No, not just purely saving data into a text file. But managing Windows user accounts. I wanted to customize my own user management tool to manage user accounts on Windows.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld: Yes, I am. Sad to hear that. Is there no other ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use WINAPI functions to manage the user profiles.

I'm posting a link to MSDN containing all the functions for use profiles - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776901.aspx

You can also see these questions - [Windows API for Creating User Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394777/windows-api-for-creating-user-profile) and [Batch Script - Create user in Windows XP programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500844/batch-script-create-user-in-windows-xp-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks. Could you also advise on any examples that I can reference to, to get myself started on the usage of WINAPI? I'm new to WINAPI and I'm not sure how I should get myself started.

Comment: Well, WINAPI is just an API - a library of functions, so you use them as you use any old function - you read the docs carefully, add the relevant headers/libs, and call the functions.

Comment: Okay. I will give it a thorough read. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Sorry. I was looking through the tutorial from this website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384843.aspx. However, I am unable to link the CreateProfile() into this tutorial. I'm not sure where I should call this and how I should call this. I googled for tutorials but to no avail. The only thing I can think of is trying to call the CreateProfile() WINAPI within the WM_PAINT case statement. Could you assist?

Comment: I don't have time to help right now, sorry, but why don't you post this as a new question on StackOverflow?